# Jquery UI autocomplete doesn't submit after Enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am working on a simple search box, where the user can type a value or select it from the dropdown menu. Now it works fine when you select form the menu, but if you press Enter, it doesn't do anything. Any help is appreciated. THanks

```
var source = [ { value: "src/devices/consoles/ps4.php",
                 label:"PlayStation 4"
               },
               { value: "src/devices/consoles/ps4.php",
                 label:"PS4"
               },
               { value: "src/devices/consoles/ps4.php",
                 label:"Sony"
               },
                { value: "src/devices/consoles/xbox.php",
                 label:"Xbox One"
               },
               { value: "src/devices/consoles/xbox.php",
                 label:"Microsoft"
               },
                { value: "src/devices/consoles/wiu.php",
                 label:"Nintendo"
              },
              { value: "src/devices/consoles/wiu.php",
                 label:"Wii U"
               }

             ];

    $("input#tags").autocomplete({
        source: source,
        select: function( event, ui ) { 
            window.location.href = ui.item.value;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event handler, try adding `val()` property and saying that you should allow the submit on `keyCode 13` which represents Enter:

```
    // ...
    select: function (event, ui) {
        window.location.href = ui.item.value;
        $(this).val(ui.item.value).val();
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#id_of_button").submit();
        }
    }
    // ...
```

Or an alternative way in your event handler, defining the keydown press to enter and trigger the click:

```
    // ...
    select: function (event, ui) {
        window.location.href = ui.item.value;
        var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
         e.which = 13;
         $("id_of_button").trigger(e);
    }
    // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#inputbox").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#submitbutton").click();
        // or $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

Resources:

- [`.submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)
- [`.keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Comment: incase if it is a `submit` button, then you can `$("#submitbutton").submit();` right?

Comment: I don't have full code so can't provide exact code. $("form").submit(); should do for him